# OPENING constant New tabs

Tags: javascript

```
var myWindow;
let urls = ["https://stackoverflow.com", "https://stackexchange.com/"];
let counter = 0;
let openWindow;
function openWin(url) {
    openWindow = window.open(url, "_blank");
}
function closeWin(){
    openWindow.close();
}
setInterval(function(){
    if(openWindow) closeWin();
    openWin(urls[counter]);
    counter++;
}, 10000)
```

this keeps opening new tabs even after opening all the urls. what to do prevent opening up any other
tabs then only url. when i load this url it open 4 url but after that open N Numbers of blank tabs.

Comment: you never check your counter `counter++;` but perhaps you need a loop on the `urls.length` value

Comment: Feels like `setTimeout` would be better than `setInterval` for your use case.

Comment: This fixes the issue but how to prevent the Popup Blocked notice by browser.

what is the best way to open URL without being blocked by browser.

Comment: Tell your users to turn off popup blocker?   https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```js
    var myWindow;
    let urls = ["https://stackoverflow.com", "https://stackexchange.com/"];
    let counter = 0;
    let openWindow;
    function openWin(url) {
        openWindow = window.open(url, "_blank");
    }
    function closeWin(){
        openWindow.close();
    }
    setInterval(function(){
        if(openWindow) closeWin();
        if((counter) == urls.length) return
        openWin(urls[counter]);
        counter++;
    }, 1000)
```

Comment: You will still be stuck with an infinite loop, even if it's doing nothing thanks to the added condition. You would need to kill the Interval.

Comment: This fixes the issue but how to prevent the Popup Blocked notice by browser.

what is the best way to open URL without being blocked by browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is great, the only problem is that the `setInterval` call will never finish unless you cancel it.

The problem with this solution is that it involves some side-effects that can be tedious to debug later.

May I propose a solution that involves less side-effects and leverage some new concepts like Promises & Async/Await contexts.

```js
"use strict";

function sleep(seconds) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        window.setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
    });
}

async function openAndCloseAfter(seconds, url) {
    const openWindow = window.open(url, "_blank");
    await sleep(seconds);
    openWindow.close();
}

async function openAll(urls) {
    for (const url of urls) {
        await openAndCloseAfter(10, url);
    }
}

openAll([
    "https://stackoverflow.com",
    "https://stackexchange.com"
]);
```

I'll let you the care of making the necessary runtime type-checking to prevent calling these functions with the wrong parameters' type.

[Here](https://repl.it/repls/DeepImmediateBaitware) is a demonstration of the above code in a real-world environment.

If you are not comfortable enough with the concepts used in the code-snippet, you can take a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/async_function).

*Note: watch-out for the browser! Since you are potentially opening lots of browser tabs, the browser might block your script unless the user explicitly tell it to ignore the multiple opened popup!*